# How to filter a elasticsearch query with items in a list

Tags: list, elasticsearch, filter

I am running an elasticsearch query but now I want to filter it by searching for the value of "result" which is already defined in the docs, going from 0 to 6. The values that I want to actually filter the search with are inside a list called "decision_results" and is defined by checkboxes on the website im running.

I tried the following code but the result of the query showed on the page does not change at all:

```py
    query = {
        "_source": ["title", "raw_text", "i_cite", "cite_me", "relevancia_0", "cdf", "cite_me_semestre", "cdf_grupo", "ramo"],
        "query": {
            "query_string":
            {
                "fields": ["raw_text", "i_cite", "title"],
                "query": termo
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        { "term": {"result": in decision_results}}
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "sort": [
            {"relevancia_0": {"order": "desc"}},
            {"_script": {
                "type": "number",
                "script": {
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "source": "Math.round(doc['cdf'].value*1e3)/1.0e3"
                    },
                "order": "desc"}},
            {"cite_me_semestre": {"order": "desc"}},
            {"cite_me": {"order": "desc"}},
            {"date": {"order": "desc"}},
            "_score"
        ],
        "highlight": {
            "fragment_size": 250,
            "number_of_fragments": 1,
            "type": "plain",
            "order": "score",
            "fragmenter": "span",
            "pre_tags": "<span style='background-color: #FFFF00'>",
            "post_tags": "</span>",
            "fields": {"raw_text": {}}
        }
    }
```

I expect to only be returned the documents with a "result" value that is inside the list "decision_results"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read a bit more about the [bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query...

replicate this structure into your query:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string":
        {
            "fields": ["raw_text", "i_cite", "title"],
            "query": termo
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {"result": in decision_results}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where your main query block is in "must" block of the bool query and "term" clause of you filter block is in the filter block of you bool query. Not sure about the syntax of the above example, haven't tested, but it should be close to that.

Also, make sure your web site handles correctly your *"term": {"result": in decision_results}* part. Is the *in decision_results* properly translated to a valid json query for your term clause? If that part is an issue, you could provide more information about the context around it so we can provide help with that.

Comment: hey, sorry for the late reply but my code is saying that the "result": in decision_results part is a syntax error, more specifically on the in part

I'm using this to fill a query variable thats going to be used by Celery to search for terms and variables in a database of docs when told so by a website search bar

Comment: Well it only means that wathever "in decision_results" is replaced with by your code is not a proper ES json formatted. you might need to pre-process it a bit to have the good synthax, then pass it into your query.